# Stacktrace filled with random caotic characters on console

Tags: java, maven, soapui, junit5

after runnig

```
mvn surefire-report:report
```

unexpectedly started to appear errors on the console similar to:

```
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateTestDescriptor.execute(TestTemplateTestDescriptor.java:107)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateTestDescriptor.execute(TestTemplateTestDescriptor.java:42)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    .NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    a
    c org.junit.platform[.enIgNiFnOe.s]u ppResourtl.thiser:ar
    h[ical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    t       at oIrNgF.Oju]n i
    .[plEaRtRfOoRrm]. engFianiel.usruepsp:o rt
    S[ierEaRrRcOhRi]c al.N o dBeFTGeTsetsTtass.kb.fegxPeocburtaenRieecLuirnsiiiv:e1l8y7 (fNaoudletTceostdTasek:. jsavoaa:p12en6v):
    T       ravte ro;r gf.ajuulnitts.tprliantgf:o rPmo.leincgyi nFea.lssuipfpoiretd. h=i=e>r aerxcpehcitceadl:. N<otdreuTees>t Tbaustk .weaxse:c u<tfea(lsNeo>de
    F[stTEaRsRkO.Rja]v a:8 4 )B
    v       Taets tjsa.vbaf.gbPaosber/ajnaiveaL.iuntiiilB.eAzrProalyOLpicsjto.nfaolrnEyacchh:(2A3r3r afyaLuilsttc.ojdaev:a :n1s501:1S)er
    er      ;a tf aourlgt.sjturniing:t .jpalvataf.olrm.aenngg.iNnuel.lsPuopipnotretr.Ehxiceerpatricohni;c aRlo.dSzaamje TshprreaawdyH:i eCrOaRrJcEhDiNc a=l=T>e setxEpectexde:c ut<otrrSueer>v ibcuet. invokwos: <false>eAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecut
    erSEeRrRvOiRce]. jav a :B3F8G)T
    asts.btf goProgb.rjaunniietL.ipnliaitBfeozrPmo.leOnpgcijnoe.nsaulpnpyocrh:233 faultcode: nst0.:hSieerrvaerrc;h ifcaaull.tNsotdreTeisntgT:a sjka.vlaa.mbldaan$ge.xNeuclultPeoRienctuerrEsxicveepltiyo$n5;( RNooddzeaTje sstpTraaswky.:j aFvIaN:J1E4D3)
    i       aNt  =or=g>. jeuxnpietc.tpelda:t f<otrrmu.ee>n gbiunte .wsausp:p <ofalsret>.h
    werarchical.ThrowableCollector.execIutNeF(OTh]r o
     ablEeRCROoRll]e ctoTre.sjtasv ar:7u3n):
    c       a2t3 ,o rFga.ijluunriets.:p l3a,t fEorrrmo.rengisn:e .0s,u pSpkoirptp.ehdi:e r0ar
    ThicIaNlF.ONo]d e
    estTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    [at EoRrRgO.Rju]n iTth.eprel aatrfeo rtme.setn gfianiel.usurpepso.r
    t
    r.lheiaesrea rrcehfiecra lt.oT hC:r\oUwsaebrlse\.weorxkescpuatcee(\TShIrS\oswoaubrlceeCso\lJUlneictt_oSro.ajapvaU:I\7t3a)
    g       eatt\ sourrge.fjiurnei-tr.epploarttfso rfmo.re ntghien ei.nsduipvpiodruta.lh iteersatr crheiscuallt.sN.o
    ,PelTeeassteT arsekf.eexre ctuot edRuemcpu rfsiilveesl y((iNfo daenTye setxTiasstk). j[advaate]:.1d2u6m)p
     [      daatt eo]r-jvgm.Rjuunn[iNt]..pdluamtpf oarnmd. e[ndgaitnee]..dsuumpppsotrrte.ahmi.e
    grhe farchiorcalke.Nd odVM teerTmineastteTda wsithout k.pexecute(NodeTerstoTpearslky. jsaavyain:84g)
    o       oadtb yjea.v aV.Mb acsrea/sjha voar. uStyislt.eAmr.reaxyiLti scta.lfloerdE?a
    C ho(mAmrarnady Lwiasst .cjmadv.ae:xe1 5/1X1 )/
    a"tC :o\rUgs.ejrusn\oarpml.ieknagcijnee\.souppepnojrdk-t1.4h.i0e.r2a_rwcihnicdaolw.sS-axm6e4T_hbriena\djHdike-r1a4r.c0h.i2c\abliTne\sjtaEvxae c-ujtaorr SCe:r\vUisceer.si(SameThread50H7i7e\raArpcphDatiac\aLloTceaslt\ETxeemcpu\tsourrSeefrivriec5e3.1j8a8v4a0:33185)0
    3a8t3 6o6r77g\.sjuurneifti.rpelbaotoftoerrm2.engi6n4e8.8s3u1p8p3o8r7t8.7h7i3e8r4a7.rjcahri cCa:l\.UNsoedresT\lAapmpbDdaat$aex\eLcouctaelR\eTceurmspi\vseulrye$f5i(rNeo5d3e1T8e8s400T3a1s5k0.0j3a8v3a6:617473 )2
    2       1a-t0 4-o2r1Tg0.9j-u1n5i-t4.6p_l1a8t1f-ojrvmm.Reunng1i nseu.rsefiurpep1o1r1t.7h1i8e0r5a3r9c4h8i7c1a2l4.5T9h4r7otwmapb lseuCroelfliecrteo_r0.1e8x6e5c3u9t8e18(7T0h8r8o2w2a5b3l6e5Ctmopl"l
    oPcrtoocre.sjsa vEax:i7t3 )C
    de      :a t0
    oCrrga.sjhuendi tt.epsltast:fo
    rpml..ennbgpi.nsei.ss2u.pwpeobrSte.rhviiecreasrTcehsitcsa.lU.KNNoFdTeeTsetsst
    ooarsg.ka.plaacmhbed.am$aevxeenc.ustuerReefciurres.ibvoeloyt$e7r(.NSuordeefTiersetBToaostke.rjFaovrkExac:e1p2t9)i
    .       :a tT hoer gf.ojrukneidt .VpMl attefrmoirnam.teendg iwniet.hsouuptp oprrto.pheirelryar cshaiycianlg. Ngoooddeb.yaer.o uVnMd (cNroadseh. joarv aS:y1s3t7e)m
    e       axti to rcga.ljluendi?t
    \javlmamtafnodr mw.aesn gcimnde..esxuep p/oXr t/C. h"iCe:r\aUrscehrisc\easptlTiaksakc.jlea\mobpdean$jedxke-c1u4t.0e.R2e_cwuirnsdiovwesl-xy6$48_(bNiond\ejTdeks-t1T4a.s0k.2.\jbaiva:127)n
    a        a-tj aorr gC.junit:.\pUlsaetrfso\eA.pspDuaptpao\rLto.chaile\rTarecmhpi\csaulr.eTfihrreo53w1a8b8l4e0C3o1l5l0e0c3t8o3r6.6e7x7e\csuutree(fTihrreobwaoboleColtlerecto2648r8.ja3v1a8:77837)8
    3       8a4t7. joarrg .Cj:u\nUiste.rpsl\AnpgpiDnae.tsau\pLpoocratl.\hTieemrpa\rscuhriecfailr.eN5o31d8e8T4e0s3t1T5a0s0k3.8e3x6e6c7u7t e2R0e2c1u-r0s4i-v2e1lTy0(9N-o1d5e-T4e6s_t18T1a-sjkv.emaRvuan:11 2s6u)r
    faitr e1or1g1.7j1u8n0i5t3.9p4l8a7t1f2o4r5m9.4e7ntgmipn es.usruepfpiorret_.0h1i8e6r5a3r9c8h1i8c7a0l8.8N2o2d5e3Te6s5ttTmaps"k
    .Perxocess Exit Code:e 0
    cCurasthee(d tests:
    NopdeTestTask.jla.va:84n)b
    p       .asti so2r.gw.ejbuSneirtv.ipcleastTfeosrtms..eUnKgNiFnTee.sstusp
    E       ratt. hoiregr.aarpcahcihcea.lm.aSvaemne.TphlruegaidnH.iseurraerfcihriec.abloToetsteErxcelciuetnotr.SFeorrvkiSctea.rstuebrm.ifto(rSka(mFeoTrhkrSetaadrHtieerr.ajracva:7hicalTes48)t
    F       eat org.apache.macven.pluugin.surtefireo.rbooterScervice.java:3l2i)ent.
    r       rkStaatrter. ruorg.junn(iFt.oprkStalrteart.fjoarmv.aengine:.3s0u5pp)o
    :       att. hoiregr.aarpcahcihcea.lm.aHvieenr.aprlcuhgiicna.lsTuersetfEixreec.ubtooort.eerxcelciuetnet(.HFioerrkaSrtcahritcearl.Treusnt(EFxoerckuStotra.rjtaevra.:j5a7v)a
    o       6a5t)
    r       ag.tj uonrigt..applaacthfeo.rmma.veenng.ipnle.usguipnp.osrtu.rheifeirraer.cAhbisctarla.cHtiSuerreafricrheiMcoajlo.TeexsetcEuntegPinreovi.deexre(cAubtset(rHaicetSruarrecfhiirceaMloTjeos.tjEanvgaa:1n3e1.j4a)v
     or     51a)t
    g       .aatp aocrhge..jmuanvietn..ppllautgfiormn.l.asuunrcehefri.rceo.rAebs.tErnagcitneSEuxreecfuitrieoMnoOjroc.heexsetcrutaetAofrt.eerxPerceuctoen(dEintigoinnseCEhxeecckuetdi(oAnbOsrtcrhaecsttSruarteafri.rjeaMvoaj:o1.0j8a)v
    g.      1a1t5 9o)r
   j       haet. moarvge.na.plaicfheec.ymcalvee.ni.nstuerrenfailr.eL.ibofoetceyrc.lFeoSrtkaerdtBeooter.mra.ien(xFecourtkee(dLBiofoetceyrc.ljeaSvtaa:r5t4e8r).
   ava:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at       java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
   0[INFO]
   9[INFO] <<< maven-surefire-report-plugin:3.0.0-M5:report (default-cli) < [surefire]test
```

and so on. Stacktrace filled with random characters.
First time in my life I see something like this. The surfire html report is filled up to the moment of these errors.  I am using parameterized tests from csv files. I don't know what to do.

```
mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: ######\apache-maven-3.6.3-bin\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\..
Java version: 14.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: #####\openjdk-14.0.2_windows-x64_bin\jdk-14.0.2
Default locale: pl_PL, platform encoding: Cp1250
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Comment: Can you write a reproducible project on GitHub? Nobody would give you a help if you have not made the project on GH.

Comment: I am unable / forbidden to give details about this project.

Comment: Can you provide me with a complete log and the dump file in target/surefire-reports?

Comment: Why is this tagged with [tag:soapui]?

Comment: Is tagged with soapui because I am using SoaupUI testSuits / testsCases from JUnit5 parametrized tests to invoke soap services.

Comment: New version 3.0.0-M6 was deployed to Maven Central. Pls let us know your feedback. Enjoy!

Comment: If this is JUnit5 test, we will fix logs chaos in M7. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1795?jql=project%20%3D%20SUREFIRE%20AND%20fixVersion%20%3D%203.0.0-M7

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the cmd.exe program.

The cmd.exe buffer cannot handle the large number of output that the tests generate.

When I invoke it like this:

```
mvn surefire-report:report > nul 2>&1
```

tests run faster and without any troubles.

Comment: It looks to me that it is another problem. IMO the maven-surefire-plugin has finished but its logs have still continued while maven-surefire-report-plugin started. I will try to find similar stackoverflow issue.